# How to use loop in where condtion in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
select * 
from student 
where roll-no in (30 to 50)
```

`student` is table name, `roll_no` and `first_name, last_name, add` are columns

How to print student details whose roll no between 30 to 50?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Select * from Student where roll-no between 30 and 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE roll-no BETWEEN 30 AND 50
```

Comment: [roll-no] or "roll-no", I believe.